# How do I Make a disabled row selectable

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I disabled certain cells via a Style for DataGridCell, but if disabled they can't be selected.

Can i make disabled cells selectable (via MVVM) without using templated columns?

Comment: For what reason do you disable the cells?

Comment: to make them read only, except one column (to change that state)

Comment: Do you have some example code?